# Filter asMap computed value maintaining sort order?

Tags: javascript, mobx

Using Mobx, I am trying to output the titles of the books from the `booksByIdMap` in the same order they are in the `booksSortedIdArray`:

```
class BookStore {
  @observable booksSortedIdArray = ["88cd7621", "88cd7624", "88cd7623", "88cd7622"];
  @observable booksByIdMap = asMap({
    "88cd7621": {
      "id": "88cd7621",
      "title": "The Secret"
    },
    "88cd7622": {
      "id": "88cd7622",
      "title": "The Alchemist"
    },
    "88cd7623": {
      "id": "88cd7623",
      "title": "Javascript"
    },
    "88cd7624": {
      "id": "88cd7624",
      "title": "PHP"
    }
  });

  @computed get byBookId() {
    return this.booksByIdMap.values().filter(b => this.booksSortedIdArray.includes(b.id));
  }
}
```

The `filter` in the `byBookId` does not seem to maintain that sort order and instead outputs:

```
The Secret, The Alchemist, Javascript, PHP
```

as opposed to:

```
The Secret, PHP, Javascript, The Alchemist
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsbin.com/lizizanize/1/edit?js,output).

How can I output the titles based on the sort order of ids in `booksSortedIdArray`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use reduce on the array and try to `get` each key from the map. If it exists, just add it to the result. [**This way you will get it in order**](http://jsbin.com/xovuwiyili/1/edit?js,console,output):

```
class BookStore {
  @observable booksSortedIdArray = ["88cd7621", "88cd7624", "88cd7623", "88cd7622"];
  @observable booksByIdMap = asMap({
    "88cd7621": {
      "id": "88cd7621",
      "title": "The Secret"
    },
    "88cd7622": {
      "id": "88cd7622",
      "title": "The Alchemist"
    },
    "88cd7623": {
      "id": "88cd7623",
      "title": "Javascript"
    },
    "88cd7624": {
      "id": "88cd7624",
      "title": "PHP"
    }
  });

  @computed get byBookId() {
    return this.booksSortedIdArray.reduce((res, el) => {
      const book = this.booksByIdMap.get(el);
      if(book) {
        res.push(book);
      }
      return res;
    }, []);
  }
}
```